# Intrapackage module loads in python

Tags: python, pythonpath

I am just starting with python and have troubles understanding the searching path for intra-package module loads. I have a structure like this:

```
top/                        Top-level package
    __init__.py             Initialize the top package
    src/                    Subpackage for source files
      __init__.py
      pkg1/           Source subpackage 1
         __init__.py          
         mod1_1.py
         mod1_2.py
        ...
      pkg2/           Source subpackage 2
         __init__.py
         mod2_1.py
         mod2_2.py          
         ...
       ...
    test/                  Subpackage for unit testing
      __init__.py
      pkg1Test/      Tests for subpackage1
         __init__.py
         testSuite1_1.py
         testSuite1_2.py
         ...
      pkg2Test/      Tests for subpackage2
        __init__.py
        testSuite2_1.py
        testSuite2_2.py
        ...
    ...
```

In testSuite1_1 I need to import module mod1_1.py (and so on). What import statement should I use?
Python's official tutorial (at docs.python.org, sec 6.4.2) says:

"If the imported module is not found in the current package (the package of which the current module is a submodule), the import statement looks for a top-level module with the given name."

I took this to mean that I could use (from within testSuite1_1.py):

from src.pkg1 import mod1_1

or

import src.pkg1.mod1_1

neither works. I read several answers to similar questions here, but could not find a solution.

Edit: I changed the module names to follow Python's naming conventions. But I still cannot get this simple example to work.

Comment: This gives me a syntax error on the dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the help of http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html (referred to in a similar question). The key point (perhpas obvious to more experienced python developers) is this:

"In order for a Python program to use a package, the package must be findable by the import statement. In other words, the package must be a subdirectory of a directory that is on sys.path. [...] the easiest way to ensure that a package was on sys.path was to either install it in the standard library or to have users extend sys.path by setting their $PYTHONPATH shell environment variable"

Adding the path to "top" to PYTHONPATH solved the problem.To make the solution portable (this is a personal project, but I need to share it across several machines), I guess having a minimal initialization code in top/setup.py should work.

Comment: the link is broken now

Answer (score 2):

The module name doesn't include the `.py` extension. Also, in your example, the top-level module is actually named `top`. And finally, hyphens aren't legal for names in python, I'd suggest replacing them with underscores. Then try:

```
from top.src.pkg1 import mod1_1
```

Comment: I changed the names to follow conventions, but I still get the same error with your suggested syntax

Comment: Is the `top` folder in your PYTHONPATH?